# How to recognize which action from new or edit in form template.

Tags: phoenix-framework

I would like to recognize in template `form.html.eex` which action from `new.html.eex` or `edit.html.eex`.

I would like to change button label.

```
<% if @action == :create do %>
  <%= submit "NEW" %>
<% else %>    
  <%= submit "UPDATE" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`Phoenix.Controller.action_name(@conn)`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#action_name/1).

Of course, you can pass it to the template as `@action` with, in your controller:

```
conn
|> assign(:action, action_name(conn))
# ...
|> render(...)
```

But if you use it often, you can override the *action* function in lib/<your_app>_web.ex:

```
def controller do
  quote do
    # ...

    def action(conn, _) do
      action = action_name(conn)
      conn = conn
        |> assign(:action, action)

       apply(__MODULE__, action, [conn, conn.params])
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Are there any parameters recognizing new or edit in form templates by default? Do I need to set action name in controller that you advised?

Comment: 1) no, the *action* field of %Ecto.Changeset{} won't be set at first 2) no, you can directly use Phoenix.Controller.action_name in your template as shown

Answer (score 1):

You pass it in from the templates. You can actually pass as many key/value pairs as you like.

For example you might have a `templates/user/edit.html.eex` like this:

```
<h2><%= gettext("Edit user") %></h2>

<%= render "form.html", changeset: @changeset,
    is_admin?: @is_admin?, user: @user, lang_select: @lang_select,
    action: user_path(@conn, :update, @user) %>

<%= link gettext("Back"), to: user_path(@conn, :show, @user) %>
```

You would just pass in one more key/value pair. Since `@action` is created by Phoenix generators to be the form action, you could just name yours `submit_text` or whatever makes sense to you. From inside the form template, it would be available like this:

`<%= submit @submit_text %>`